# IBM Cognos Report Studio: Inserting Data Items from same Dim on Report Page

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I have tried to insert two data items to the report page, in which one is an element from a dimension (lets say CurrentItem), and the other one is just

```
parent(CurrentItem)
```

I have already done the same for elements from another dimension, which worked out fine after associating the page with the query. However, for these two elements I get the following error:

*XQE-PLN-0213 The report nests levels from hierarchies 'DimName' breaking the hierarchy level order. Please nest levels according to natural hierarchy level order.*

This page should have provided me with a solution: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/upgrade_and_migration/bi/page568.html

However, as I already have done this with another dimension for the same query in the same report, it does not really make sense.

It might be worth adding that the following query expression is defining one of the rows in my query:

```
descendants([CurrentItem], 1)
```

But, removing this row does not make any change. The only way I get rid of the error is when I remove one of the data items that I have inserted directly on the page.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening / not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This just sounds like one of the ways DQM "breaks" report with its stricter rules than CQM. Im confused as to the need for the parent/descendant functions; can't you simply drag in the specific level of the dimension you're working with and let Cognos generate the appropriate reference?

Comment: You may be right about the DQM rules breaking the report, however, it is wierd that the operation is possible with one dimension, but not with two dimensions. Im not sure how dragging a specific level would select the parent node of a dynamically selected element? Would it not just give me all the elements of that specific level?

Comment: I'm not entirely visualizing your report, but it is clear to me that you'll have to take a different approach due to DQM. Can you nest the dimensions under each other instead of using two columns?